# For a graph $G = (V,E)$, show it contains at least $|E| - |V| + 1$ cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I started trying to prove by induction on $|E|$, using the characterization of trees, but cannot get any further. 
Is this a good way to proceed or shall I try something else?

The start of my induction proof had that $G$ is a graph $|E|>|V|- 1$.
Hence, $G$ is not acyclic, thus it must contain a cycle $C$.

Unsure how to move on from here

Comment: There are no *planar* graphs mentioned here; I don't think I see how Euler's formula applies.

Comment: Induction on the number of edges is a fine way to go. What's your base case? Can you write out the start of your (failed) induction attempt so that we can help you proceed?

Comment: I've now started trying to do it by considering a spanning tree of G which has (n-1) edges, and then looking at what adding an edge does in relation to creating a cycle. Is this a better method? 
How do I show it is the minimum number of cycles, and not just an equality?

Comment: That's exactly the wrong way to go about an induction argument. The right was is to say "Suppose I start with $G$, and remove a single edge <perhaps some special kind of edge> to produce $G'$, which has fewer edges and <perhaps some condition on connectedness>. Then the number of cycles in $G'$ is <at least something> and therefore <with some argument here> the number of cycles in $G$ is <at least something>." You also note that in the base case, $G$ has no edges <of the required kind> to be removed, but some easy theorem shows that the number of cycles is then at least $|E| - |V| + 1$.

Comment: "Hence $G$ is not cyclic" ???? Is that really what you wanted to say?

Answer (score 2):

For each component of a forest, we have that $E_i=V_i-1$, $E=\sum E_i, V=\sum V_i$. We also know, that for a tree, any addition of an edge adds at least one cycle.
Thus, take each connected component of your graph and remove $c_i$ edges, thus that your graph is now a forest with each tree satisfying: $$E_i-c_i=V_i-1$$ Now add all the $c_i$ edges back, thus creating at least: $$c=\sum c_i = \sum E_i-V_i+1=E-V+1$$ cycles. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This works modulo connectedness; if your graph $G$ is not a connected graph, it doesn't have a spanning tree to begin with. (Of course, then you can work with each of the connected components of $G$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov - corrected accordingly, though proof remains the same.